How to visualize GraphvizAlgorithm<Type, Edge<Type>> object to PNG or SVG in C#?
I'm working with the GraphvizAlgorithm<Type, Edge> class in my C# project and I need to visualize this object as a PNG or SVG image. I've created the graph and added the necessary nodes and edges. However, I'm unsure how to render this object into an image format.
Here is a simplified version of what I'm working with:
GraphvizAlgorithm<Type, Edge<Type>> graphviz = new GraphvizAlgorithm<Type, Edge<Type>>();
// Add nodes and edges to graphviz


How can I convert this graphviz object to a PNG or SVG file in C#?
I've looked into the QuickGraph documentation but couldn't find a straightforward example for this specific class. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!
I expected to find a method within the QuickGraph.Graphviz library that would allow me to export the graph to a PNG or SVG file directly. Ideally, I am looking for a way to:

Use a tool or library to render this DOT string as an image file (PNG or SVG).

